# Nginx redirect a particular page from https to http

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

How can I redirect a specific https page to http, example:
https://example.com/foo -> http://example.com/foo
Only for the page foo, and no other page.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
  listen      443;
  ssl         on;

  location /path/to/your/page {
    return 301 http://domain.com$request_uri;
  }
  ...
```

Then you'll need the corresponding block that has:

```
server {
   listen         80;
   ...
```