# Permanent Redirect for HTTPS

Tags: nginx, redirect

301 is a permanent redirect for http.

Is there a similar code for https?  I googled and found nothing.  I am looking at the best way to make an NGINX redirect.

I have a solution in place, but I am trying to see if there is a better method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protocol is exactly the same between HTTP and HTTPS: HTTPS is HTTP encapsulated within SSL. All the request and response codes remain the same.

See [Nginx redirect a particular page from https to http](https://serverfault.com/q/449960/3139) and use the inverse of my answer there.